# How can I apply administrator right on more than one person in all the board of a Trello organisation?

Tags: trello, access-control, trello-boards

I created a Trello organization with 3 boards.

This organization reflect an IRL association were IRL admin are 3 person. I want them to have the same rights (administrator) and could invite people, archive document & board, create board, etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Add and Edit member permission in each board you create.

When you create each board also assign those same three people.

Open each board and click on each icon / name in turn. (Top right corner where the member icons are)  Use the "Change permissions..." link to make each an Admin for each board.

You can also edit their permissions in the Organization list too.  However, that gives them control over all the organization settings.